# Checking android emulator is in Silent Ringer Mode or not

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I am developing an android application for which i want to know whether the android phone is silent or not. I need to know how can I check this thing on android emulator by code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AudioManager class for your requirement,

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

if (am.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT) 
{
    // silent mode
}
```